# INSERT INTO does not work in a stored precedure

Tags: sql

I wrote this precedure that checks certain conditions and then runs an INSERT or UPDATE base on the data. However, for some reason the INSERT does not execute.

```
IF @sid = ''
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Book_Art (Sub_ID, Art_IDs, P_ID) VALUES (@Sub_ID,@art_id,@P_ID)
    END
ELSE IF @aids = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @comma = ''
        UPDATE Book_Art SET Art_IDs = + @aids + @comma + @art_id WHERE Sub_ID =  @Sub_ID AND P_ID = @P_ID
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @comma = ','
        UPDATE Book_Art SET Art_IDs = + @aids + @comma + @art_id WHERE Sub_ID =  @Sub_ID AND P_ID = @P_ID
    END
END
```

Comment: 1st, please confirm you have verified that `@sid` is in fact an empty string and not a `null` or a space or something else

Comment: Don't forget you need to commit your inserts.

Comment: Not sure what kind of database you're working with, but typically you can quickly debug this kind of thing with print statements.  If you're in a situation where there is no console to output to, you could also try manually raising an exception and include the value of @sid to see if your code is even being reached.

Comment: Yes I did. ^@sid is empy. I figured it out. By chnaging ^@sid= '' to @sid is null

Comment: I strongly recommend coding `coalesce(@sid,'') = ""` instead of `@sid is null` in order to get in the habit of coalescing **all** nullable values before putting them into a predicate. Otherwise you will be chasing down *my excluded middle disappeared* bugs all day long.

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced the following:

```
IF @sid = ''
```

With:

```
IF @sid is null
```